# How to add data in CalendarRulesType attribute using c# in Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

Can anybody give an example or ref link for how to add data or create a record with CalenderRules type attribute using c# in dynamics crm.

Information about CalenderRules type attribute is displayed in below link.but can't find actually how to add.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn817862.aspx#BKMK_Image

Answer (score 2):

From the article you have referenced.

> ***There are no actual attributes that use the CalendarRulesType***. When using the early binding style, the code generation tool will create the following two simulated attributes that are not present in the metadata. These attributes actually represent a view of the calendar rules records associated in a ***one-to-many relationship to the entity instance***.

Just like any other relationship, you can use [Associate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309247.aspx) or just use the early/late bound attributes and reference the entity collection:

Early/Late bound:

```
calendar.CalendarRules = new[]
{
   new CalendarRule()
   {
      Id = calendarRuleId
   }
};
```

Associate:

```
 organizationService.Associate(Calendar.EntityLogicalName, calendarId, new Relationship("calendar_calendar_rules"),
                new EntityReferenceCollection(new[]
                {
                    new EntityReference(CalendarRule.EntityLogicalName, calendarRuleId)
                }));
```